# Java - Spring injected RegEx - Illegal Character - Ampersand

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring to inject a RegEx pattern from a properties file but I'm running into an error involving the Ampersand.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal
character range near index 34 [ A-Za-z0-9¦#_/<>[]():^¬+=%$£!`@'-&,.";*?\€]
```

My expression is:

```
[ A-Za-z0-9\¦#_/<>[\]():^¬+=%$£!`@'\-\u0026,.";*?\\\u20AC]
```

It works on [RegExPal](http://www.regexpal.com/)

I've tried escaping the character and using UniCode but I still get the same error.

Does anyone know if there's something in Java / Spring that's causing this to happen?

Comment: Does it require an XML like notation? Try `&amp;` Also, the `-` should be better placed at the end of the character class. You also need to escape the `[` (if it is a Java regex). Note that RegexPal only tests JavaScript and PCRE regexps. Try `[ A-Za-z0-9¦#_/<>\\[\\]():^¬+=%$£!\`@'\\u0026,.";*?\\\\\\u20AC-]`, BTW, if this is not inside an XML.

Comment: The hyphen was treated as  a range defining character inside the character class (see `'-&`), hence the error message (`&` is decimal 38 and `'` is decimal 39, but a range must follow an ascending order).

Comment: Any feedback? Did any solution work for you? Shall I post mine?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry for the delayed response. Anubhava's solution has worked for me. Didn't get to check until just a minute ago. Thankyou for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double escape the hyphen or keep it at first or last position in your character class:

```
[- A-Za-z0-9¦#_/<>[\\]():^¬+=%$£!`@'\\u0026,.";*?\\\\\\u20AC]
```

You can clearly see from the error that it has removed the escaping here:

```
character range near index 34 [ A-Za-z0-9¦#_/<>[]():^¬+=%$£!`@'-&,.";*?\€]
```